# AH00135 : Invalid method in request CCM_POST

Tags: php, apache, http, post, wampserver

In my project running on `wamp` server, I have a error on my "apache_error_log" that looks like this :

```
AH00135: Invalid method in request CCM_POST /ccm_system/request HTTP/1.1
```

I dont know if this is related to my code which is :

```
$filtre = array('nom'=>"$nom", 'prenom'=>"$prenom", 'matricule'=>"$matricule");
```

The Array gets emptied.  But, when I add this before the array, the array has the values.

```
$nom = $_POST['nom'];
$prenom = $_POST['prenom'];
$matricule = $_POST['matricule'];
```

I have seen a project working with the same code but the array gets the value and nothing was added. I don't know if we need to include some PHP extension or module.

Can someone tell me if it's related or not?

Tanks you

Comment: `CCM_POST` is an invalid method. It should be `POST`. Double-check the method on your form.  Of course, the issue may not even be coming from your server and may be some other system attempting to access it. Check the IP the request is coming from.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/167026/what-is-a-ccm-post-http-request

Comment: Tank you  @aynber, indeed it is another badly configured web server which sends me these requests.